# Does the phrase "fix a schedule" sound natural, if does, then what is its exact meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

When I want choose a date for, say, a party, does it sound natural to say the following?

> Let's fix a schedule for the party.

If that sounds ok, then could I change *fix* for *set*?

Comment: For ***a schedule***, I'd probably use ***draw up*** rather than ***set** [up/down]* or ***fix***. To my ear, things are slightly different when the referent is simply something that needs needs a single value, such as *Let's **fix / set** a **date / venue** for the party*, where ***fix*** carries stronger implications of ***a date / venue which will not be subsequently changed*** (whereas you might ***set** a date* just so you've got *some* kind of plan, even if it might change later).

Answer (score 1):

A [**schedule**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/schedule) is rather more than just fixing a date. It's more appropriate for a *series* of events, such as a conference with registration, talks, meals etc.

If you are choosing a date for some event, that's not a schedule, its just, well, a *date*.

> Let's fix a date for the party.

Although more idiomatic (for me) would be

> Let's set a date for the party.

Comment: As I commented above, the ***date*** or ***venue*** for a party are just single values. But as you say, a ***schedule*** is much more than a single value. You could still "fix" it though.